# How can I display model items in the layout view without it disturbing other model views?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

To clarify, I'm trying to display incoming requests in a notification styled manner in my `login partial` view. This works all fine when the page I'm currently looking for is the index of that specific model.

```
@model IEnumerable<ResultatenSysteem.Models.OpleidingAanvraag>
```

Otherwise it throws an error :

> InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the
>   ViewDataDictionary is of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List1[ResultatenSysteem.Models.Resultaat]',
>   but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[ResultatenSysteem.Models.OpleidingAanvraag]'.

How can I display items of model `OpleidingAanvraag` inside of my partial view, which is displayed on every page?

To be clear:
This error gets thrown every time I try to acces an page that is other than OpleidingAanvraag Index. This is because index is of type: 
`@model IEnumerable<ResultatenSysteem.Models.OpleidingAanvraag>`

Every other page will give an error similair to what is above, which I think is because it's trying to load two models.

Comment: could you add your `Action method` to question.

Comment: you may create a sperate partial view and place it on a layout.

Comment: What is a `ResultatenSysteem.Models.Resultaat` in relation to a `ResultatenSysteem.Models.OpleidingAanvraag`? Are they related?

Comment: No, to clarify. This error is unique to the specific page I tried to open up, this is because the page is trying to load two models, I think. OpleidingAanvraag has items that I want to display in the partial view (which will be displayed on every single page the site has)

Comment: @SatishSingh how would I do so? And wouldn't I still get an error since the page is trying to load up multiple models?

Comment: I assume you have something in your view or layout which looks like this `@Html.Partial("partialname")`. There is an overload on this method which is the model you have to pass to the partial. If you do not use this overload ASP.NET uses the Model of the current page, which is probably of another type. 
`@Html.RenderAction` Is something you want to look at.